# compilation error: No suitable bison/yacc found

Tags: linux, gcc, bison, yacc, yocto

I am using gcc8.2 and linux operating system. I have bison package installed. Still I am getting the below error:
    echo "*** Error: No suitable bison/yacc found. ***"
    echo "    Please install the 'bison' package."
    exit 1

I have checked the "$ac_cv_prog_YACC" and it is not having any value. It should be set to "bison -y" if bison is already installed.

Any idea why $ac_cv_prog_YACC does not have any value?
I got this error when compiling the conntrack-tools package (version 1.0.1)

Comment: Did you look in `config.log` to see the output of the failing tests?

Comment: I have checked config.log but i didnot find ac_cv_prog_YACC variable at all. In pass logs ac_cv_prog_YACC is set to bison -y (pass log is when gcc version is 7.3 and I was using yocto sumo version. problem is seen after upgrading to yocto to thud and gcc to 8.2 )

Answer (score 2):

You say

> I have bison package installed.

But the test in the `./configure` file disagrees. That means that it cannot find an executable file named `bison` anywhere in your `$PATH`. You should start by verifying that `$PATH` has the correct value and that there is an executable named `bison`. (Apparently the `./configure` script for conntrack-tools only looks for `bison` and `byacc`, and not for `yacc`.)

I don't know much about `yocto` but I did find the following note in a change log for version 2.5.1:

> bison-native no longer included in many dependency chains meaning some recipes need bison-native adding to DEPENDS